# Is there a way to login in django rest api in browser without UI?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm doing backend project in which I need to do an API without any UI. In this API there's no registration (only by admin UI), but I need a way to log in, because I need some "pages" to be only for logged in users.
I set up token authentication, each user has their token created.

Is there a simple way to make some login "form" with serializer? I mean "page" in which there is only two fields (for username and password) and ability to POST this to get authenticated and then go back to "login only pages"?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn about the rules of the site as well as [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: Maybe Django REST Auth is the solution for you: https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth

Comment: Okay, I've just changed to SessionAuthentication and it's working as I wanted, but I've got only one field to put JSON format text and I would like to have separate text pole for username and password. Any help with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to try DjangoREST browsable API: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/. It is included into DRF, so you do not need to install any extras. In order to use the browsable API, just type the endpoint url into your browser. If you are using ModelSerializers, then forms for data input will be generated automatically, otherwise you will have to enter data as a JSON.

add to settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'
    ),

    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',

    ),
}
```

add to urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Thank you! I think it'll solve all the problems.